# can't set countifs formula to cell with macro vba excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to write a macro that input a countifs formula to cell

What is my mistake?

```
Dim ReferSheet As String
ReferSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffSet:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets(ReferSheet).Range("D8:D1103"), " >= " & Worksheets("Display").Range("C9"), Worksheets(ReferSheet).Range("D8:D1103"), " <= " & Worksheets("Display").Range("H9"), Worksheets(ReferSheet).Range("L8:L1103"), " > " & 0)"
```

Comment: In general with formulas that you want to write into a worksheet from VBA: you can first write the formula in the worksheet, then use the macro recorder to see how the syntax would look in VBA (start recording > go to the cell with the formula > F2 (or click into the cell) > Enter > stop recording

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. I built an intermediate string and used `debug.print` as a means to inspect the string to make sure it is what you want.
2. Once you are sure you have what you want, you can eliminate the intermediate string and debug.print statement, and use the equation directly in the assignment of `ActiveCell.Formula`

The code ...

```
Sub t1()
Dim ReferSheet As String
Dim formulaStr As String

    ReferSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffSet:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Select
    formulaStr = "=CountIfs($D$8:$D$1103," & """>=""" & " & $C$9," & "$D$8:$D$1103," & _
                     """<=""" & " & $H$9," & "$L$8:$L$1103," & """>0""" & ")"
    Debug.Print formulaStr
    ActiveCell.Formula = formulaStr
End Sub
```

The result ...

```
=COUNTIFS($D$8:$D$1103,">=" & $C$9,$D$8:$D$1103,"<=" & $H$9,$L$8:$L$1103,">0")
```

Comment: Nice work.  John, notice how he uses double "double quotes" when a "double quote" is needed. He's also concatenating "ReferSheet" into the formula.